# Clientside validation not working with sub-properties in ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an object named *User*, with a property *Name*, with a *Required* attribute.

```
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a textbox, like so:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name) %>
```

When enabling clientside validation, *Name* is perfectly validated client side.

However, if I create a ViewModel where User is now a property

```
public class UserModel
{
     public User TheUser { get; set; }
     public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and create my textbox

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TheUser.Name) %>
```

then clientside validation fails. The form is posted without client validation picking up the error.

<strike>It looks like the javascript *window.mvcClientValidationMetadata* gets filled up as before, with no noticeable difference.</strike>

What gives? Is there something i need to do?

I'm using

- ASP.NET MVC 2 RC2 (with .NET 3.5/VS2008)
- MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation.js from the latest Futures download

**Edit:**

Upon closer inspection *window.mvcClientValidationMetadata* isn't filled up as it should. No ValidationRules are specified:

```
{"FieldName":"TheUser.Name","ReplaceValidationMessageContents":true,"ValidationMessageId":"TheUser_Name_validationMessage","ValidationRules":[]}
```

Comment: Can you please show your User class definition?

Comment: any updates on this issue? did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should create an editor template for your class User.  Load it with 
Html.EditorFor(model => model.User, "User"), with "User" being the name of your editor template.

The user class should be the view model for this editor template.

Then, within your editor template for user, call the editor templates for its properties.

MVC's out of the box client validation should work correctly with this.